# verilog code in Ise

Tags: verilog

I have synthesized my Verilog code in ISE Project Navigator 2013. my device is xc3s400-5pq208. now I want to map my code to analyze timing and the errors are:

```
ERROR:Pack:2309 - Too many bonded comps of type "IOB" found to fit this device.
ERROR:Pack:18 - The design is too large for the given device and package. 
Please check the Design Summary section to see which resource requirement for your design exceeds the resources available in the device.
```

the number of bonded IOBs in Design Summary: used = 177,available = 141 , utilization = 125%
what is the solution for this problem? I must change my code?

Answer (score 1):

The top-level module in your design has too many IOs (bonded comps type "IOB") to fit the selected FPGA.

Either you have a mistake in your design, e.g. wrong top-level module, or your design simply try to use more IOs than then selected FPGA has available.

Answer (score 0):

this means that your design has more inputs and output than actual FPGA device you have chosen. try to choose different FPGA version in the device properties window.[image]

by clicking this you can change the device type
[image]

[image]

by changing the device you can able to synthesize it